# AJAX hidden call jsp page

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, jsp

i have my index.jsp :

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>Hello</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       Hello !
       <input type="hidden" name="ip" value="" id="ip">
    <script>

        var ip = document.getElementById("ip");
        ip.value = userip;

    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have another view.jsp which one take an argument like that :

http://localhost:8200/view/view.jsp?ip=IP_VALUE

Then when i open this link and replace IP_VALUE by anything, this value is automatically added to my database.

But now i'm trying to call hiddenly this jsp page, i mean i want that when the user open my page, my javascript variable "ip" is past to my view.jsp like :

http://localhost:8200/view/view.jsp?ip= "ip"

But i want that the user don't see that, so i don't want any redirection or form, just an AJAX hidden call of my jsp.

view.jsp is on the same folder than my index.jsp

How can i do that hiddenly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>Hello</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       Hello !
       <input type="hidden" name="ip" value="" id="ip">
    <script>

        var ip = document.getElementById("ip");
        ip.value = userip;

        var xmlhttp =  new XMLHttpRequest();

        xmlhttp.open('GET', 'view.jsp?ip' + userip, true);

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {

                if(xmlhttp.status == 200) {

                    //alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
                }
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.send(null);

    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can send any value to any page by [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/XMLHttpRequest) object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Actually i'm at work i'll could try it in 3 hours. Anyway, this method won't open the page for the user ? and don't i have to write "view.jsp?ip=" with the **=** or not ? Thanks again !

Comment: Actually ya have not send ip address to the server from client side. Because when you execute your page view.jsp It will already get access to all headers with necessary to us IP address. Open page by Ajax It is like when you clicking a link with the center wheel of the mouse, it would open that link in a new tab). But in case of Ajax this operation will flow at background)

Comment: Ok it's exactly what i want, i don't want the user see any new tab opening or any redirection, just stay on my index.jsp to use it while i send the ip in a hidden way. Thanks a lot !